# Separate name from payment

Tags: r, regex

I'm new at R and would like some help.

I have a data frame containing names and corresponding fee for service payments, in this format:

```
"Doe, Jane 12,345.67"
"Doe, John 1,234,567.89"
"Doe-Smith, Adam 999,000.00"
```

The name and payment are in a single column right now. How would I be able to extract the payments and put them in a new column? I tried using regex and so far I have:

```
.*\s(\d+,*\d+,*\d+.\d+)
```

It seems like it's working to match the string and capture the salary, but where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the names can never contain any digits, there is a fairly straightforward approach here using `sub`:

```
df <- data.frame(data=c("Doe, Jane 12,345.67",
                        "Doe, John 1,234,567.89",
                        "Doe-Smith, Adam 999,000.00"))

df$payment <- sub(".*?(?=\\d)", "", df$data, perl=TRUE)
df$name <- sub("\\s+\\d+.*", "", df$data)
df

                    data      payment            name
1        Doe, Jane 12,345.67    12,345.67       Doe, Jane
2     Doe, John 1,234,567.89 1,234,567.89       Doe, John
3 Doe-Smith, Adam 999,000.00   999,000.00 Doe-Smith, Adam
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @TimBiegeleisen's solution but with conversion to `numeric`:

```
# Sample data
s <- c("Doe, Jane 12,345.67",
"Doe, John 1,234,567.89",
"Doe-Smith, Adam 999,000.00")

as.numeric(gsub(",", "", sub(".+\\s(\\d+[\\d\\.,]+)", "\\1", s)))
#[1]   12345.67 1234567.89  999000.00
```

Explanation: Use `sub` to remove name part and only keep the numbers including decimal separator; then use `gsub` to globally remove decimal separator and convert to `numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `separate` from tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%separate(data,c("names","payment"),"(?<=[a-z])\\s")
            names      payment
1       Doe, Jane    12,345.67
2       Doe, John 1,234,567.89
3 Doe-Smith, Adam   999,000.00
```